# PayPal sandbox card number is not working

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have implemented PayPal payment method in my website. I am testing in sandbox right now. I got a credit card number from a website https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm
Card number is 4111111111111111.
When I use this card number with expiry date 03/2018, it works flawlessly but when I use the same card number with 12/2020, it does not work. Can anyone please tell me its reason? 
Thanks and best regards

Comment: What sort of response does it return when you try using the expiry date 1220?

Comment: It says internal error

Comment: Can you please try this scenario at your end? I hope being very experienced, you will be able to catch it.

Comment: I don't have a current PayPal-capable site on my dev server right now to test with, sorry.